# How to translate a mobile jQuery menu?

Tags: javascript

`Drupal.t('Select a page')` is not translated into another language (mobile menu) after clearing cache and translating strings through the translation menu. What should be added or changed to get translation?
Theme [Growth Lite](https://www.drupal.org/project/startupgrowth_lite) (jquery.mobilemenu.js)

```js
var settings = {
    combine: true,  //combine multiple menus into a single
select
    groupPageText: 'Main',  //optgroup's aren't selectable, make an option for it
    nested: true,                   //create optgroups by default
    prependTo: 'body',              //insert at top of page by default
    switchWidth: 480,               //width at which to switch to select, and back again
    topOptionText: Drupal.t('Select a page')    //default "unselected" state
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it was not clear but there is an option in the theme itself to put change the phrase 'Select a page' and it becomes untranslatable. You have to remove it in the theme itself and change it in the file jquery.mobilemenu.js and then translate it through Drupal.